# Explicit cross coverage definition

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

1.Is it possible to explicitly list cross coverpoints in system verilog ? Something like below..

2.Since I am only interested in the occurrences of doublets `{{1,2},{3,1},{2,4}}` and not `b1`or `b2` standalone, can I accomplish this without creating coverpoints `b1` and `b2` (i.e just write cross coverage)?

```
covergroup test1 with function sample(int i,int j) ;  
  type_option.comment = "Config";
  b1:coverpoint int {bins m1[]={1,2,3};}
  b2:coverpoint int {bins m2[]={1,2,4};}
  mx :cross     int,int
                   {
                     bins mx1[] ={{1,2},{3,1},{2,4}};
                   }
endgroup
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want a `cross` for what you are trying to cover. Bins for a cross are for merging or excluding tuples, not creating them. You probably want to use a simple coverpoint

```
cp: coverpoint {i,j} {
   bins mx[]= { {32'd1,32'd2},{32'd3,32'd1},{32'd2,32'd4} };
}
```

or more simply

```
cp: coverpoint {i[3:0],j[3:0]} {
  bins mx[]= { 'h12,'h31,'h24 };
}
```

Comment: It's going to look kind of awkward in the report, though. I'd still go for cross coverage and set the weights on the single coverpoints to 0.

Comment: @Tudor, it really depends on what the OP was looking to cover.

Comment: @dave_59 isn't this approach just concatenating two integers ? What if if i and j are enums ?

Comment: Yes. You can concatenate two enums just as easily.

Comment: Thanks..But the bins end up showing on the report as `bin_00010002` when `enum1=1` and `enum2=2` were concatenated(Less readable like Tudor mentioned). Is it possible to explicitly list cross coverages (My question#1) ?